# Prove that a real normed space $V$ of dimension $n$ is disconnected in two connected parts by any linear subspace of dimension $n-1$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, normed-spaces, connectedness, topological-vector-spaces

> **Theorem**
>
> All norms on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ are equivalent.
>
> *Proof*. Omitted.

So to follow we will use the infty norm $\lVert\cdot\lVert_\infty$ given by the equation
$$
\lVert\vec v\lVert_\infty=\max\{|v^i|:i=1,...,n\}
$$
where $v^i$ is for each $i=1,..,n$ the $i$-th componet of $\vec v$ with respect any basis.

So let be $V$ a finite dimensional real vector space and so let be $W$ the subspace spanned by the $(n-1)$ vectors $\vec v_1,...,\vec v_{n-1}$, that is $W$ is the set of linear combinations of these such vectors. Now by standards theorems of finite dimensional vector spaces it must exist a vector $\vec v_n$ that is not linear combination of the above vectors and additionally any vector of $V$ is a linear combination of this vector and of the preceding ones, that is for any $\vec v\in V$ there must exist $n$ scalars $v^1,...,v^n$ such that
$$
\vec v=v^i\vec v_i
$$
where in the above identity I have used the Einstein convention. So we define the sets $X$ and $Y$ by letting that
$$
X:=\{\vec v\in V:\lambda^n>0\}\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,Y:=\{\vec v\in V:\lambda^n<0\}
$$
so that $V\setminus W=X\cup Y$ and thus if we prove that these sets are open then the statement follows. So for $\vec v\in V$ we observe that if $\vec u\in B(\vec v;v^n)$ then
$$
|u^n-v^n|\le\max\{(u^i-v^i):i=1,...,n\}=\lVert\vec u-\vec v\lVert_\infty<v^n
$$
so that
$$
-|v^n|<u^n-v^n<|v^n|
$$
from which we conclude that if $\vec v\in X$ then $\vec u\in X$ and if $\vec v\in Y$ then $\vec u\in Y$ so that these two sets are open.

So I ask if what I tried to prove is effectively true and if my arguments are correct. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: With a first look your proof looks correct, assuming of course that the vector space is taken over the field of real numbers.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Yes, I assume implicitly that the vector space is taken on the field of the real numbers: anyway do you know if the result is true for a complex space too?

Comment: No, for example take $\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}$ and the subspace $\{(z,0): z\in\mathbb{C}\} $. The complement is then equal to $\{(z,w): z,w\in\mathbb{C}, w\neq0\}$ which is path-connected, as it is homeomorphic to the product of the plane with the punctured plane (both are connected, so the product is connected).

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Could you edit your comment? There is an error in the latex and thus I have some difficult to read it, sorry.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Okay, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof seems correct, but it's overly complicated.

Let $H$ be a subspace of $V$ of dimension $n-1$. Pick a basis $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{n-1}\}$ of $H$ and complete it to a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},v_n\}$ of $V$.

Define the linear map $f\colon V\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(v_1)=f(v_2)=\dots=f(v_{n-1})=0,\quad f(v_n)=1
$$
Then the map $f$ is continuous (prove it) and its kernel is $H$, which is therefore closed. Now
$$
A=\{v\in V:f(v)>0\},\quad B=\{v\in V:f(v)<0\}
$$
are nonempty disjoint open sets and $V\setminus H=A\cup B$. They are not empty because $v_n\in A$ and $-v_n\in B$.

Comment: Oh yeah! this is surely more simple. Thanks to much for your assistance!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro It exploits that every linear map between finite dimensional normed spaces is continuous.

Comment: Yes, it exploits that the kernel of a linear map between topological vector space is a closed set, right? I studied it on the text *Functional Analysis* by Walter Rudin.